# Save data between different database version

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database and its new version with changed reports, changed forms but with absolutly the same tables structure. The problem is that proper tables entries is stored in the old database.

How can I replace tables entries in new database with tables entries in old database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a split database? You should be, so it would not matter that the back-end data was stored in an MDB and the front-end in an ACCDB.